# How do coupling capacitors in transistor not affect biasing?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, amplifier, coupling, biasing

[image]
[image]
I understand the usefulness of the capacitors in an amplifier circuit but i dont understand why we use one at the input? and how does this not affect the biasing if it removes the dc voltage?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you show us a circuit schematic that's an example of your concern?

Comment: Usually the biasing would happen on the transistor side of the capacitor

Comment: Hi, Saif. I think the best way to imagine here is that a capacitor "charges up" to exactly the mean (average) difference voltage between the prior stage's DC output quiescent point and the next stage's DC input quiescent point. (Ignoring the capacitor for a moment.) So, for example, if the output DC quiescent point is +10 V and the input DC quiescent point is +2 V, then the capacitor will develop just the right value, -8 V, across it to permit those two DC quiescent points to co-exist. And it will *mostly* hold that voltage across it, if its size is well-selected, as AC swings take place.

Answer (score 5):

> how does this not affect the biasing if it removes the dc voltage?

A capacitor doesn't remove DC voltage; it blocks DC voltage. It prevents the DC voltage on one side of the capacitor affecting the DC voltage on the other side of the capacitor. It allows two circuits with their own biasing DC conditions to remain independent but share the same AC signal (coupled by the capacitor).

Comment: thank you for your answer but what i dont understand is that if the dc is blocked on the transistor side of the capacitor then how is the transistor biased?

Comment: If it helps Saif, the capacitor "charges up" to some DC value. Initially, capacitors appear as a short-circuit. To "charge up" takes time (and energy), and once it reaches some DC value, that value doesn't want to change. Once charged, the capacitor takes no more energy, so appears like an open-circuit. That is why capacitors "couple" AC and "block" DC. (The *inverse* is true with inductors; they start charging like an open-circuit and gradually become like a short-circuit, or "block" AC and "couple" DC.)

Comment: @saif the transistor must be biased locally for it to work correctly. That bias circuit and the DC level it produces will not be passed by the capacitor to circuits on the other side of the capacitor and neither will the DC level be affected. If in doubt still, add a diagram to your question so that I can be more specific.

Comment: @Andyaka yeah i get why we have to add the capacitors but if no dc passes from the input to the Base of the transistor then how will it be biased correctly

Comment: The circuit you added will have no DC biasing but that doesn't mean it can't work as a class C amplifier (used in power RF applications) or the biasing has been left out by mistake. Where did the circuit diagram come from?

Comment: its from my lecture notes, i'll add the whole slide

Comment: @Andyaka I get it now thanks a lot i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

It **does** affect the DC biasing.  That's why it's there.

If you're reveiving a signal into an amplifier circuit, you have little control over what DC offset it has.  So it's common to add a capacitor to block any DC component in the signal, so that you can add another DC bias (not shown in your example), so that the transistor works correctly.

Without the capacitor, the incoming DC bias might be too low to turn the transistor on at all, or it may be so high that it drives the transistor into saturation.